# Java: List how to get specific element on a line

Tags: java, list

I'm trying to get a specific element from a list, but not the entire list. For example if I do

```
System.out.println(words.get(0))
```

I would get

```
[16, Matthew, 13,954, Alexis, 8,181]
```

But how would I get a specific element on this line, like the name Matthew and not the whole line.
`[Matthew]`

```
 List<List<String>> words = topNames.stream()
                .map(sentence -> sentence.split("\\s+"))
                .map(Arrays::asList)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());


            System.out.println(words.get(0));
```

Comment: What's the point of `i`?

Comment: I got rid of it , but I was looping through everything on the list before just to make sure it works.

Comment: I think you're looking for `words.get(0).get(1)`.

Comment: THANK YOU. I couldn't find out anywhere

Comment: Except you knew it already. There's no fundamental difference between `get(0)` and `get(1)`.

Comment: Yes but I saw people say that to do this you would have to do something like .get(0)[1] which wouldn't work

Comment: You're confusing list syntax with array syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `map()` operation to map to the elements at the specified index :

```
 List<String> wordsAtTheOneIndex = topNames.stream()
                .map(sentence -> sentence.split("\\s+"))
                .map(Arrays::asList)
                .map(l -> l.get(1))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @Workkkkk How do you know?

Comment: `Arrays::asList` is a bit redundant now. Just do `.map(a -> a[1])`.